# Adding multiple child views to parent view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a `LinearLayout` view element inside a `ScrollView` (**main.xml**):

```
<ScrollView ...>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/root"
       android:orientation="vertical"
    >
          <TextView .../>
          <EditText .../>
          ...
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As you see above, there are also some other elements inside the *root* `LinearLayout` .

Now, I would like to programmatically(dynamically) add more views to the `LinearLayout` (id="root").

**I tried the following way to add more child views** to this *root*:

**Firstly,** I created my child view which is in a separate layout file:

**child.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/child"
>
     <TextView id="mytxt"... />
     <ListView id="mylist".../>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Secondly,** I inflate & get two instances of above child view, initialize elements inside:

```
/***inflate 1st child, initialize its elements***/
LinearLayout child_1 = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
TextView txt1 = (TextView)child_1.findViewById(R.id.mytxt);
txt1.setText("CAR");
ListView list1 = (ListView)child_1.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
// Code to initialize 'list1' (I did not paste code here)


/*** inflate 2nd child, initialize its elements ****/
LinearLayout child_2 = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
TextView txt2 = (TextView)child_2.findViewById(R.id.mytxt);
txt2.setText("PLANE");
ListView list2 = (ListView)child_2.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
// Code to initialize 'list2' (I did not paste code here)
```

**Finally**, I add them to *root* `LinearLayout`:

```
//get root
View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.root);

//add child views
root.add(child_1);
root.add(child_2);
```

When I run my app on device, I can only see `child_2` layout without seeing `child_1` under 'root', why??

Answer (score 2):

in LinearLayout default orientation is horizontal set it vertical.......

from
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

see

The default orientation is horizontal.

```
and you set text in txt1.setText("PLANE"); set in  txt2.setText("PLANE");
```

`both text set in same textview`.....

```
    txt1.setText("CAR");
    txt1.setText("PLANE");
```

Comment: but you set text in txt1.setText("PLANE"); set in  txt2.setText("PLANE");

Answer (score 1):

How do you create your layout? Do you do it through `setContentView(int)`? Then you should retrieve that instance by doing this in your activity:

```
findViewById(R.id.root);
```

Comment: I dont understand you, I am using "(LinearLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.root);" , what is wrong with this???

Comment: Do you use setContentView(int) somewhere in your activity to set the layout? Perhaps I was wrong in assuming you do this, but if that is the case then that is the source of your error. So do you use it?

Comment: Perhaos you could dump the entire class on pastebin or something?